# How to get a readable text copy of a dataframe using Python?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe and I want to print it using a printer or get a hard copy of a dataframe. I have almost 30 columns and hundreds of rows in that dataframe. I just want to get a printed copy of it in any format.

I tried making a PDF of it and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> but the dataframe values were not readable. Same with HTML too. I just want the data to be readable. How can I do so?

I am creating an application for those people who are not really familiar with using computers. So I hope for a simple and easy answer.

I already understand that I could use `to_excel` and `to_csv`. However, then the user would have to open an Excel file and click on print. I would like it to be more simple and easy for use than that.

Comment: You want for the user to just click on the program. And the program should do some calculations and then print it by itself? Am i understanding this correctly?

Comment: There will be a print button first the user will enter dates and then the calculations will be done then a dataframe will be displayed that df should be printed by clicking on a button

Comment: Well if you are asking for idea how to do it this is not the site for this. But i recommend you to use some kind of GUI like tkinter then link button to fucntion that will save the file then right click it and select print

Comment: i m using tkinter for this application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting it to Excel and printing would be an option.

`pd.to_excel()`

Comment: Using `df.to_csv()` will be more robust to Excel's tendency to (mis!)-interpret raw data values.

Comment: But i am creating an applications for those people who are not really familiar using computers so can the answer be more simple i got it that i can use to_excel and to_csv also but then the user has to go to excel file and click on print.i want it that it can be more simple and easy for the user

Comment: @KushagraJain - Please *update the question* accordingly, and specify *all* requirements.